# Is it possible to get a list of pages a user navigated through to get to a page? (All of the hops they took)

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

If I have a user that navigated from `Page A` --> `Page B` --> `Page C`, is there a way of seeing from `Page C` all of the previous pages they navigated through to arrive at `Page C`? Is there a history of "hops" saved by Google Analytics?

I know previous page can be seen, which would return `Page B` but I'm after the previous of the previous here.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use Navigation summary report (a tab in All pages report). In this report you can see the next and previous pages to the one selected, and change the selected page, for example with one of the previous ones so you can see which are the previous pages to it.

Comment: Is it possible to query this (at bulk) with the API?

Comment: You can query the pages and the relative previous pages and of these with a for loop to query the respective previous pages.
Simply manage the API limits correctly (i.e. 10 queries per second: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/mcf/v3/limits-quotas) and write the output in a comprehensible way.